# Execute a field calculation on just selected records from Processing Toolbox in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-3, qgis-modeler

When I try to do a field calculation from the Processing Toolbox in QGIS 3 it performs the calculation on all records instead of the selected records. Is there a way to have the calculation performed only on the selected records using the Processing Toolbox Field Calculator?

The field calculator from the menu bar includes an option to "Only update [X] selected records" but that is missing from the Processing Toolbox.

Here's the dialog box from the Processing Toolbox:
 [image: Processing Toolbox Field Calcator]

Here's from the menu bar (and the attribute table)

[image: Menu Bar Field Calculator]

I'm ultimately setting this all up in the Graphical Modeler so if there's a work around that fits there, that's ok.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `is_selected()` function in `if` statement to perform calculation on just selected features.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

May be update to QGIS 3.2. It works at me

[image]
[image]

--EDIT--

In the Processing toolbox, it works with an extraction (but not with a selection). I don't understand the difference

[image]

Comment: Sorry, i have read the message form @JS_UNC too rapidly. May be my edit can help him

Comment: Interesting. As I understand it Extraction creates two layers from an input layer, so it makes sense that then the field calculator would work on the extracted layer because it is still performing the calculation on all records - this time its the records in the extracted layer.