# In QGIS 3 modeler how do you get an input to connect to a 'Select/Extract by attribute'?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-modeler

In QGIS modeler I have added an input CSV but can only connected to files open in the workspace. How do I get it to connect to the input file like https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/291183/2891

Input
[image]

Extract / or Selection doesn't allow me to choose the Input file...but lists the tables open in the workspace.
[image]

**UPDATE**
When I change the input layer to 'Using model input' I don't get any options in the drop down. Have I defined my input wrong?
[image]

Here's my .model3 code

```
<!DOCTYPE model>
<Option type="Map">
  <Option name="children" type="Map">
    <Option name="native:fieldcalculator_1" type="Map">
      <Option value="true" name="active" type="bool"/>
      <Option name="alg_config"/>
      <Option value="native:fieldcalculator" name="alg_id" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="" name="color" type="QString"/>
      <Option name="comment" type="Map">
        <Option value="" name="color" type="QString"/>
        <Option value="" name="component_description" type="QString"/>
        <Option value="60" name="component_height" type="double"/>
        <Option value="320" name="component_pos_x" type="double"/>
        <Option value="115" name="component_pos_y" type="double"/>
        <Option value="100" name="component_width" type="double"/>
        <Option value="true" name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool"/>
        <Option value="true" name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool"/>
      </Option>
      <Option value="Field calculator" name="component_description" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="30" name="component_height" type="double"/>
      <Option value="304.5" name="component_pos_x" type="double"/>
      <Option value="216.5" name="component_pos_y" type="double"/>
      <Option value="200" name="component_width" type="double"/>
      <Option name="dependencies"/>
      <Option value="native:fieldcalculator_1" name="id" type="QString"/>
      <Option name="outputs" type="Map">
        <Option name="PCL_v1" type="Map">
          <Option value="native:fieldcalculator_1" name="child_id" type="QString"/>
          <Option value="" name="color" type="QString"/>
          <Option name="comment" type="Map">
            <Option value="" name="color" type="QString"/>
            <Option value="" name="component_description" type="QString"/>
            <Option value="60" name="component_height" type="double"/>
            <Option value="0" name="component_pos_x" type="double"/>
            <Option value="0" name="component_pos_y" type="double"/>
            <Option value="100" name="component_width" type="double"/>
            <Option value="true" name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool"/>
            <Option value="true" name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool"/>
          </Option>
          <Option value="PCL_v1" name="component_description" type="QString"/>
          <Option value="58" name="component_height" type="double"/>
          <Option value="459.5" name="component_pos_x" type="double"/>
          <Option value="325.5" name="component_pos_y" type="double"/>
          <Option value="200" name="component_width" type="double"/>
          <Option name="default_value" type="invalid"/>
          <Option value="false" name="mandatory" type="bool"/>
          <Option value="PCL_v1" name="name" type="QString"/>
          <Option value="OUTPUT" name="output_name" type="QString"/>
          <Option value="true" name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool"/>
          <Option value="true" name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool"/>
        </Option>
      </Option>
      <Option value="true" name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool"/>
      <Option value="true" name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool"/>
      <Option name="params" type="Map">
        <Option name="FIELD_LENGTH" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" name="source" type="int"/>
            <Option value="10" name="static_value" type="int"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="FIELD_NAME" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" name="source" type="int"/>
            <Option value="PCL" name="static_value" type="QString"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="FIELD_PRECISION" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" name="source" type="int"/>
            <Option value="0" name="static_value" type="int"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="FIELD_TYPE" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" name="source" type="int"/>
            <Option value="2" name="static_value" type="int"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="FORMULA" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" name="source" type="int"/>
            <Option value="regexp_substr(&quot;Document Description&quot;,&#xd;&#xa;'^\\d+-v1-\\s?\\d+\\s*(\\d+)')" name="static_value" type="QString"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="INPUT" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" name="source" type="int"/>
            <Option value="BuildingRegister_Sheet1_e85756d7_267a_45d9_ba22_1524b285e20d" name="static_value" type="QString"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
      </Option>
    </Option>
    <Option name="qgis:selectbyattribute_1" type="Map">
      <Option value="true" name="active" type="bool"/>
      <Option name="alg_config"/>
      <Option value="qgis:selectbyattribute" name="alg_id" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="" name="color" type="QString"/>
      <Option name="comment" type="Map">
        <Option value="" name="color" type="QString"/>
        <Option value="" name="component_description" type="QString"/>
        <Option value="60" name="component_height" type="double"/>
        <Option value="540" name="component_pos_x" type="double"/>
        <Option value="215" name="component_pos_y" type="double"/>
        <Option value="100" name="component_width" type="double"/>
        <Option value="true" name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool"/>
        <Option value="true" name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool"/>
      </Option>
      <Option value="Select by attribute" name="component_description" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="30" name="component_height" type="double"/>
      <Option value="192.625" name="component_pos_x" type="double"/>
      <Option value="132.875" name="component_pos_y" type="double"/>
      <Option value="200" name="component_width" type="double"/>
      <Option name="dependencies"/>
      <Option value="qgis:selectbyattribute_1" name="id" type="QString"/>
      <Option name="outputs"/>
      <Option value="true" name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool"/>
      <Option value="true" name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool"/>
      <Option name="params" type="Map">
        <Option name="FIELD" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" name="source" type="int"/>
            <Option value="Document Description" name="static_value" type="QString"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="INPUT" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" name="source" type="int"/>
            <Option value="BuildingRegister_Sheet1_e85756d7_267a_45d9_ba22_1524b285e20d" name="static_value" type="QString"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="METHOD" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" name="source" type="int"/>
            <Option value="0" name="static_value" type="int"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="OPERATOR" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" name="source" type="int"/>
            <Option value="7" name="static_value" type="int"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option name="VALUE" type="List">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" name="source" type="int"/>
            <Option value="'%-v1%'" name="static_value" type="QString"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
      </Option>
    </Option>
  </Option>
  <Option name="designerParameterValues" type="Map">
    <Option value="G:\Projects\076_Monthly_DCDB_Update\Working\current\input\BuildingRegister.xls" name="BuildingRegister" type="QString"/>
    <Option value="true" name="VERBOSE_LOG" type="bool"/>
    <Option name="native:fieldcalculator_1:PCL_v1" type="QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition">
      <Option type="Map">
        <Option name="create_options" type="Map">
          <Option value="System" name="fileEncoding" type="QString"/>
        </Option>
        <Option name="sink" type="Map">
          <Option value="true" name="active" type="bool"/>
          <Option value="1" name="type" type="int"/>
          <Option value="TEMPORARY_OUTPUT" name="val" type="QString"/>
        </Option>
      </Option>
    </Option>
    <Option name="native:fieldcalculator_2:PCL_Blank" type="QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition">
      <Option type="Map">
        <Option name="create_options" type="Map">
          <Option value="System" name="fileEncoding" type="QString"/>
        </Option>
        <Option name="sink" type="Map">
          <Option value="true" name="active" type="bool"/>
          <Option value="1" name="type" type="int"/>
          <Option value="TEMPORARY_OUTPUT" name="val" type="QString"/>
        </Option>
      </Option>
    </Option>
    <Option name="native:fieldcalculator_3:survey_temp" type="QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition">
      <Option type="Map">
        <Option name="create_options" type="Map">
          <Option value="System" name="fileEncoding" type="QString"/>
        </Option>
        <Option name="sink" type="Map">
          <Option value="true" name="active" type="bool"/>
          <Option value="1" name="type" type="int"/>
          <Option value="G:/Projects/076_Monthly_DCDB_Update/Working/current/scratch/SurveyPlans.TAB" name="val" type="QString"/>
        </Option>
      </Option>
    </Option>
    <Option name="native:mergevectorlayers_1:Updated_Building_List" type="QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition">
      <Option type="Map">
        <Option name="create_options" type="Map">
          <Option value="System" name="fileEncoding" type="QString"/>
        </Option>
        <Option name="sink" type="Map">
          <Option value="true" name="active" type="bool"/>
          <Option value="1" name="type" type="int"/>
          <Option value="G:/Projects/076_Monthly_DCDB_Update/Working/current/scratch/Building_List.TAB" name="val" type="QString"/>
        </Option>
      </Option>
    </Option>
  </Option>
  <Option name="groupBoxes"/>
  <Option name="help"/>
  <Option name="modelVariables"/>
  <Option value="" name="model_group" type="QString"/>
  <Option value="model" name="model_name" type="QString"/>
  <Option name="parameterDefinitions" type="Map">
    <Option name="BuildingRegister" type="Map">
      <Option value="0" name="behavior" type="int"/>
      <Option value="G:\Projects\076_Monthly_DCDB_Update\Working\current\input\BuildingRegister.xls" name="default" type="QString"/>
      <Option name="defaultGui" type="invalid"/>
      <Option value="Building Register" name="description" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="" name="extension" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="All Files (*.*)" name="filefilter" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="0" name="flags" type="int"/>
      <Option value="" name="help" type="QString"/>
      <Option name="metadata"/>
      <Option value="BuildingRegister" name="name" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="file" name="parameter_type" type="QString"/>
    </Option>
    <Option name="native:fieldcalculator_1:PCL_v1" type="Map">
      <Option value="true" name="create_by_default" type="bool"/>
      <Option value="-1" name="data_type" type="int"/>
      <Option name="default" type="invalid"/>
      <Option name="defaultGui" type="invalid"/>
      <Option value="PCL_v1" name="description" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="0" name="flags" type="int"/>
      <Option value="" name="help" type="QString"/>
      <Option name="metadata"/>
      <Option value="native:fieldcalculator_1:PCL_v1" name="name" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="sink" name="parameter_type" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="true" name="supports_append" type="bool"/>
      <Option value="true" name="supports_non_file_outputs" type="bool"/>
    </Option>
  </Option>
  <Option name="parameterOrder"/>
  <Option name="parameters" type="Map">
    <Option name="BuildingRegister" type="Map">
      <Option value="" name="color" type="QString"/>
      <Option name="comment" type="Map">
        <Option value="" name="color" type="QString"/>
        <Option value="" name="component_description" type="QString"/>
        <Option value="60" name="component_height" type="double"/>
        <Option value="320" name="component_pos_x" type="double"/>
        <Option value="15" name="component_pos_y" type="double"/>
        <Option value="100" name="component_width" type="double"/>
        <Option value="true" name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool"/>
        <Option value="true" name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool"/>
      </Option>
      <Option value="BuildingRegister" name="component_description" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="30" name="component_height" type="double"/>
      <Option value="120" name="component_pos_x" type="double"/>
      <Option value="60" name="component_pos_y" type="double"/>
      <Option value="200" name="component_width" type="double"/>
      <Option value="BuildingRegister" name="name" type="QString"/>
      <Option value="true" name="outputs_collapsed" type="bool"/>
      <Option value="true" name="parameters_collapsed" type="bool"/>
    </Option>
  </Option>
</Option>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the left of the `input layer` dropdown you need to switch from `value` to `model input` (third available option). Then you may choose the csv you are inputting, provided you load the csv as `vector layer` and don't require a geometry on it.

[image]

Comment: When I do this I still don't see any of the input files. I've updated the question with the code from my model3 -what settings am I missing?

Comment: @GeorgeC: Since you're loading a file and the layer isn't already in the project (which wasn't clear at the beginning) I suggest you try `native:loadlayer` (this tool is exclusive to the modeller) or `native:filedownloader`. You may hand your path to both tools and use their output as input for your `select by attribute`. This is theoretical, I haven't tried with dummy data.

Comment: The issue is that the Selection and Field Calc tools when set to 'Using model input' don't recognise the file that's loaded using native:loadlayer or inputs:File/Folder - can you share the model3 code from your example?

Comment: I think the overall issue might be you're trying to load an `.xlsx` file, which QGIS can't really work with @GeorgeC

Comment: I tried it separately with csv files as well.

Comment: I found the issue - I had to use Inputs::Vector Layer and then Geometry type::Not required. Finally to connect from Field Calc to the selection I had to use 'Using algorithm output' and not 'Model input'

Comment: @GeorgeC great, I edited the answer accordingly.